# Why does attempting to estimate the entropy of text by randomly choosing chars in it and counting how often they are equal give wildly wrong results?

Tags: probability-theory, information-theory, entropy

Why does attempting to estimate the entropy of a string, by randomly choosing pairs of (not necessarily adjacent) characters in it, and counting how often the selected characters in the pairs are equal, give wildly wrong results? Here is a MatLab program that exemplifies that, also available [on my blog](https://flatassembler.github.io/toponyms.html):

```matlab
% Ovo je MatLabski program koji uspoređuje rezultate koje daje moj algoritam
% procjenjivanja entropije s rezultatima koje daje Shannonov algoritam.
suglasnici = 'bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz';
testni_stringovi=cell(100 - length(suglasnici) + 1, 1);
for koliko_cemo_staviti_b_ova = 100 - length(suglasnici) + 1 : -1 : 1
  for i = 1 : koliko_cemo_staviti_b_ova
    testni_stringovi{koliko_cemo_staviti_b_ova} = [
      testni_stringovi{koliko_cemo_staviti_b_ova} 'b'
    ];
  end
  for i = 1 : 100 - koliko_cemo_staviti_b_ova
    testni_stringovi{koliko_cemo_staviti_b_ova} = [
        testni_stringovi{koliko_cemo_staviti_b_ova} suglasnici(int32(floor((i - 1) / (100 - koliko_cemo_staviti_b_ova) * (length(suglasnici) - 1))) + strfind(suglasnici, 'c'))
        ];
  end
end
samarzijine_entropije = [];
shannonove_entropije = [];
for i = 1 : length(testni_stringovi)
  str = testni_stringovi{i};
  samarzijine_entropije = [samarzijine_entropije samarzijina_entropija(str)];
  shannonove_entropije = [shannonove_entropije shannonova_entropija(str, suglasnici)];
end
sgtitle('Usporedba Shannonove i Samarzijine entropije generiranih stringova');
subplot(1,2,1);
plot(shannonove_entropije, samarzijine_entropije);
xlabel('Shannonova entropija');
ylabel('Samarzijina entropija');
subplot(1,2,2);
plot(shannonove_entropije);
hold on;
plot(samarzijine_entropije);
xlabel('Broj b-ova u stringu');
ylabel('Entropija (bit/simbol)');
legend('Shannonova entropija', 'Samarzijina entropija');
function ret = shannonova_entropija(str, suglasnici)
  apsolutne_frekvencije = [];
  for i = 1 : length(suglasnici)
    apsolutne_frekvencije = [apsolutne_frekvencije 0];
  end
  for i = 1 : length(str)
    znak = str(i);
    apsolutne_frekvencije(strfind(suglasnici, znak)) = apsolutne_frekvencije(strfind(suglasnici, znak)) + 1;
  end
  relativne_frekvencije = apsolutne_frekvencije / length(str);
  ret = 0;
  for relativna_frekvencija = relativne_frekvencije
    if relativna_frekvencija > 0
      ret = ret - log2(relativna_frekvencija) * relativna_frekvencija;
    end
  end
end
function ret = samarzijina_entropija(str)
  broj_pokusaja = 10000;
  broj_pogodaka = 0;
  for i = 1 : broj_pokusaja
    prvi = int32(floor(rand() * length(str) + 1));
    drugi = int32(floor(rand() * length(str) + 1));
    if str(prvi) == str(drugi)
      broj_pogodaka = broj_pogodaka + 1;
    end
  end
  omjer_pogodaka = broj_pogodaka / broj_pokusaja;
  ret = -log2(omjer_pogodaka);
end
```

Here is what outputs:
[image: What the MatLab program outputs]
So, what is going on here? I would expect the curve on the left to be approximately a y=x straight line, and the curves on the right to be approximately identical. But obviously, they are not. My algorithm for estimating the entropy gives close-to-correct results (or slightly overestimates them) when the entropy of the string in question is high, but it severely underestimates entropies of low-entropy strings.

Comment: Why do you expect it to work?

Comment: Consider a source of the form $0101010101\ldots$ How would you differentiate it from a completely random source?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Well, as far as I understand it, such a source would have an entropy of exactly 1 bit per symbol

Comment: The source is entirely predictable. It has entropy zero. What is your definition of entropy?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, well, my definition of entropy is the way it is usually defined, as the sum of the products of negative (usually binary) logarithms of the probabilities of symbols times the probabilities (relative frequencies) of those symbols.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I thought it was obvious why I expect it to work, I mean, that is almost the definition of entropy.

Comment: The entropy of a (discrete) *random variable* $X$ is $\sum_x \Pr[X=x] \log (1/\Pr[X=x])$. You were discussing the entropy of text, so for you $X$ is the text. Hence the definition you gave is not quite the way it is usually defined.

Comment: You seem to be estimating what is known as [collision entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy#Collision_entropy), which is different from Shannon entropy. In both cases, you are estimating the entropy of the empirical distribution of the text.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I must admit I do not see the difference.

Comment: The entropy of a constant random variable is zero. The entropy of the empirical distribution of a text is zero iff it consists of a single letter. The latter can be used to give a (rather bad) estimate of the former.

Comment: For example, the entropy of the constant random variable which is always equal to $01$ is zero, but your formula gives the answer $1$ (assuming you use base 2).

Comment: If you try to estimate the entropy of English using your method, you will get an estimate which is a lot higher than the real entropy per letter. You can take a look at the [classic paper of Shannon on the topic](https://www.princeton.edu/~wbialek/rome/refs/shannon_51.pdf).

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Where would you recommend me to read more about it? I know only what we are taught at school, and I haven't even heard of collision entropy. We have been taught what Shannon Entropy is, but apparently in a simplistic manner.

Comment: You can start with the Wikipedia article. The subject might also be covered in standard textbooks such as Cover & Thomas' Elements of Information Theory.

Comment: We discourage posting code.  Not everyone reads Matlab.  Instead, please use concise pseudocode or mathematics.  This is not a coding site and code is off-topic here.